# Using JQuery to run loading animation (error handling)

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery (JS) beginner here. I am creating a simple loading animation for a file upload form via JQuery. The objective is to show the animation once an `Upload` button is pressed *and a file was chosen by the user*. In case no file was chosen and solely `Upload` was pressed, do nothing.

Currently, relevant parts of my code are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if ($('#p2').change(function())){
       if ($("#Btn2").bind("click", function(event))){
           $("#loader2").show();
           $("#spinner2").show();
           $("#Btn2").hide();
       }
   }
});
```

Looks straight forward enough but doesn't work (nothing happens). Perhaps I'm making a rookie mistake. Can someone help rectify this? Ask me for more code in case needed.

Comment: What is purpose of `if` and nested event handlers? Can you include HTML at Question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `if`, un-nest `click` event handler from within `change` event handler. At `click` at `#Btn1` element check `#p1` `.files` `.length` to determine if user has uploaded file objects

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#p1").change(function(event) {
    // do stuff with files
  });
  $("#Btn1").on("click", function(event) {
    if ($("#p1")[0].files.length) {
      // user has upload files
      $("#loader1").show();
      $("#spinner1").show();
      $("#Btn1").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#loader1,
#spinner1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
  <input type="file" id="p1">
  <input type="button" value="upload" id="Btn1">
</form>
<div id="loader1">uploading</div>
<div id="spinner1">spinner</div>
```

Comment: What do you precisely mean by *do stuff with file* in your code snippet?

Comment: User uploads files. Presumably you will do stuff with the uploaded files within `change` event. Though what you do with the `FileList` or `File` object is not part of the original Question. The Question is how to determine that user has uploaded files at all, and if that is true, call `.show()` and `.hide()` on several elements

Comment: Oh I see, that's what you meant

Comment: @guest271314 I think my answer is simpler in terms of jQuery. It gets the job done and is easier to comprehend from Hassan Baig's perspective.

Comment: @shahz _"I think my answer is simpler in terms of jQuery."_ Where does your Answer check if user has uploaded a file?  _" It gets the job done and is easier to comprehend from Hassan Baig's perspective."_ How can you determine another viewers' perspective?

Comment: @guest271314 hhhmmmmm you are right when it comes to keep in mind the check that a file has been uploaded and only then the animation should run. In my code the animation would run when the user uploads a file and clicks on the upload button but yes it would also run if the user has not uploaded a file and just clicks on the upload button. When it comes to fulfilling the requirement you are very right about your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the following jQuery code which is shorter and simpler to understand for a beginner such as yourself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#p1').change(function(){
        $('#Btn1').bind("click", function(event){
            $("#loader1").show();
            $("#spinner1").show();
            $("#Btn1").hide();
        })
    })
```

Not only is this code easier to understand for a beginner but it actually gets the job done i.e. you upload a file, click on the upload button and your loading animation will run and once the file is uploaded your animation will stop running and the upload button will disappear.